# Is it possible to arrange remote attendance at Family Law court hearing in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, family-law, court, barristers

It is possible to hire a barrister and be represented.

Is it possible  to hire a barrister and be represented and have a Skype / Hangouts / anything running during the court hearing?

---

Previous question: [What happens if I don't show up to the Court (DRA, Family Court, UK)?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/26794/what-happens-if-i-dont-show-up-to-the-court-dra-family-court-uk)

At the end decided to fly back to the UK and attend the court hearing.

Personal rant aside, it was a complete waste of time, waste of money and I'd be very happy to arrange a remote attendance: **barrister + Skype**.

In one of the court rooms I saw instructions related to video system so surely there is such option...

**Before I call the court and ask them, maybe you'll know how is it regulated?**

Answer (score 2):

The signs you saw are almost certain to have related to [this](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/how-video-hearings-are-speeding-up-court-cases), a system where defendants in prison can appear remotely. The key to this system is that both locations (the court and the prison) are secure and under the control of the Judicial System, as is the hardware and software controlling the link between them.

It could happen under other circumstances (for example a witness not being available at court), but I would think that the odds of being able to do this from an unsecured location - and particularly using third party hardware and software - would be [sorry for my choice of words] remote.

That said, this is SE, and I'm sure anyone with experience to the contrary will jump in.

Comment: I have known the High Court to take witness evidence by videolink from abroad when necessary. The court met in the Law Society conference suite (since it was a few hundred yards from the building; presumably other fine videolinks are available), at a time when the witness would be available at the foreign end of the link, and the English court staff administered the oath at a distance. That said, OP seems to assume that he can instruct his barrister what points to take, which would be wrong even if he were present: see [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/9011/4595).

Comment: @TimLymington - So have I, now you've mentioned it (I thought about possible witness testimony as I was driving home yesterday). Thanks. Editing.